# SQL Oracle distinct group by

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, between

I have a table like this.

```
ID | PACKAGE
1      250
1       1
2       1
2      160
2      250
3       1
3      251
4      25
4       1
```

I want to get ids that have package no between 250 and 251 but not have another package except than package no 1.

My desired result is something like this:

```
ID  |  PACKAGE
3       1
3      251
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use `in/not in` function, for example:

```
select distinct id, package from table where package in (250, 251, 1);
```

Or if you need exclude interval:

```
select distinct id, package from table where package = 1 or package between 250 and 251;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from table where package between 250 and 251  or package=1;
```